# How to get the first 6 texts

Tags: python, loops, text, rating

for now I have an output with many ratings, and would want to only print out the first sixth in python.

```
import re
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/').text
titles = re.findall('/title/\w*/(?=">)', data)
rating = re.findall('\d\.\d.*ratings', data) 

rating
```

output I got :

```
['8.8 based on 716,954 user ratings',
 '8.8 based on 1,729,095 user ratings',
 '8.8 based on 1,937,913 user ratings',
 '8.7 based on 1,902,393 user ratings',
 '8.7 based on 2,167,514 user ratings',
 '8.7 based on 1,544,013 user ratings',
 '8.7 based on 1,203,819 user ratings',
 '8.6 based on 1,753,684 user ratings',
```

Comment: There is already an answer. Here is the document to let you know more about it： https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first six items in the list by this:

```
your_list[:6]
```

**EDIt**

```
for i in range(0,len(user_ratings)):
   user_ratings[i] = f"No {i+1}: {user_ratings[i]}" 
user_ratings[:6]
```

OR

```
user_ratings = [f"No {i+1}: {user_ratings[i]}" for i in range(0, len(user_ratings))]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using rating = ratings[:6]

print (rating), but I am not sure how to add the No. in front for every movie

Comment: don't use a function name `list` as a variable name.

Comment: I meant a list not the function name.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you actually want to get the initial six elements of `user_ratings`.
You can use list slicing to do the same. Further, you can use list comprehension and f-strings to add text before the ratings:

```py
initial_six = user_ratings[:6]

formatted_text = [f'No.{initial_six.index(i)+1}: {i}' for i in initial_six]
print(formatted_text)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the output becomes  'No.1:No 1: No 1: No 1: No 1: 9.2 based on 2,460,830 user ratings', 'No.2:No 2: No 2: No 2: No 2: 9.1 based on 1,702,153 user ratings'.... can it be showing only one No.1 and a line break after the commas?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does not repeat like that. Make sure you are copying correctly. As for line breaks, `formatted_text` is a list. You can simply convert it to a string with `'\n'.join(formatted_text)` and it would print nicely

Answer (score 0):

`user_ratings[0:6]` will print out the first six elements in the list `user_ratings`

Comment: Hi, I tried using rating = ratings[:6]

print (rating), but I am not sure how to add the No. in front for every movie

Answer (score 0):

Try this! The below code will resolve your problem:

```
import re
import requests, pprint

data = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top').text
titles = re.findall('/title/\w*/(?=">)', data)
rating = re.findall('\d\.\d.*ratings', data)

rating_arr = []
for rate in rating[0:6]:
    rating_arr.append("No. {}: ".format(rating[0:6].index(rate) + 1) + rate)

pprint.pprint(rating_arr)
```

The output looks like:

```
['No. 1: 9.2 based on 2,460,844 user ratings',
 'No. 2: 9.1 based on 1,702,157 user ratings',
 'No. 3: 9.0 based on 1,182,290 user ratings',
 'No. 4: 9.0 based on 2,416,183 user ratings',
 'No. 5: 8.9 based on 728,548 user ratings',
 'No. 6: 8.9 based on 1,265,055 user ratings']
```